# jQuery: wait for an element (video tag - dynamically generated) to load

Tags: jquery, load, html5-video, onload, dynamically-generated

Without using timeout, I want to use jQuery to check for a video tag which is soon to be generated. At the time we are looking for the video tag, it does not exist yet.

I could use window.load to wait for the whole window loaded, then call the callback function:

```
window.load = function () {player = jQuery("#videoid"; }
```

but is there anyway to "wait" until that particular video tag inserted/loaded into the body then execute the callback func? something like:

```
jQuery("#videoid").bind('load', function() { player = jQuery("#videoid"); })
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can delegate a bind to the `DOMNodeInserted` event for the element so when it's inserted an event handler will run. This doesn't work in IE8 and older, but neither do `<video>` tags:

```
jQuery(document).delegate('video', 'DOMNodeInserted', function () {
    alert('Wana watch a video?');
});
```

Note that `$(<root element>).on(<event>, <selector>, <event handler>)` is the same as `$(<root element>).delegate(<selector>, <event>, <event handler>)`.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vW4Pg/

**UPDATE**

If you're interested in implementing this idea, make sure to take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events

Thanks for the comment @JFK.

Comment: SIMPLY BRILLIANT! I had been looking for this DOMNodeInserted for hours!! Thank you Jasper!

Also, thanks for your note on ".on"

Comment: @SimpleCode I'm glad I could help. If you found my answer helpful and that it correctly answered your question, I'd appreciate if you marked the answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: In case someone comes across this (old) answer, this is something to bear in mind https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events